# Can I hang a key hanger without attaching it to a stud?

Tags: drywall, anchor

I am trying to mount a key hanger on a wall, I drilled two holes in the dry wall, they went right through with little or no resistance, I'm guessing because there was no stud behind the wall. I stuck two plastic anchors into the holes, am I safe to hang that key hanger from the holes without ripping up the wall?

Comment: Can this be generalized for any light weight hanging needs? Maybe < 2lbs? It would be more useful in the future to other users that way I would think.

Comment: I think you're right. Sorry for the incomplete question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Monkey hooks](http://www.monkeyhook.com/) are great.

[image: Monkey hooks]

Modify the hook using wire snippers.  It leaves a tiny hole in the wall and they hold up to 50 pounds.  Very very solid for heavy things.  I trust these much more than screw+anchor - if I can get these to work for the application.  They wont work for everything (like blind housing that has to screw in) but for anything to "hang" they work.

Comment: These things are fantastic! I bought like 10 of these. They work fantastic! The package says they hold 35lbs a piece.

Comment: Good to hear they work.  They work even better with some pliers - if you bend the ends in you get the bottom "v" of the hook to jam in the hole.

Answer (score 5):

Key racks tend to be fairly light, so you shouldn't have any problems using only drywall anchors.